# TortoiseHG slow over VPN

Tags: vpn, tortoisehg

I'm using TortoiseHG over quite a slow VPN and it is essentially unusable.  Any operation takes forever to complete, if it completes at all.

I work on a local clone of a repository and push or pull changes over a mapped network drive to a repository on a server.  However trying to do anything on the server repository takes an age.

Are there any settings that can be changed to make TortoiseHG run faster over a slow connection.  Or is there an alternative I could use whilst working remotely whilst still using TortoiseHG when in the office.

Comment: Running it over, e.g., ssh would probably be faster than a Windows file share. See also http://superuser.com/questions/43686/setting-up-a-remote-mercurial-repository

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial is a distributed version control and hence has some advantages over a server-based tool.

It is possible for example to "bundle" (`hg help bundle`) particular changesets. This creates a usually very small zipped file, because this file only contains the changesets you selected. If you know, which changeset is at least existing at the destination office, you select this one up to the tip and call `hg bundle --base 123 filename.hg` where 123 is the changeset number that is already present at the destination.

This file can be transferred by mail, USB stick or carrier pigeon between your offices. On your destination, "unbundle" it into the repository, which works like a "push".